# Embed app's window into another app

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, opengl, handle

I managed to get a correct HWND handle of an app based on PID of the app. How can I embed window pointed to by the handle or more preferably it's OpenGL render context into my application, preferably into a viewport?

Comment: You can't expect to do this. Sorry.

Comment: Unless you control both processes, and both processes are prepared to build a cross-thread window hierarchy, you cannot safely do this. See [Is it legal to have a cross-process parent/child or owner/owned window relationship?](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20130412-00/?p=4683)

Comment: I'm really curious now: why is this such a common question?

Comment: Well, that's a pity. Thanks for clearing this one up for me